# Angular 6 - modify index.html file reference path when building

Tags: angular, angular6

When building angular 6 app, the scripts files are generated and so the css file. All the files have the hashed value in the end.

Is it possible to modify the index.html links for these files? The path is always local file but if i upload them on some server i want for example tho add a custom variable url i have in environment.prod.json.

Comment: You don't need to: the index.html file is also generated, and contains scripts that refer to the scripts and css files that have been generated. Look in your dist folder.

Comment: This behavior is controlled to some extent by Angular CLI (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build). Check out options --base-href and --deploy-url. Hashes are controlled by --output-hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create a custom index.html (e.g. index.prod.html) for each environment:

Create in your `src` folder another copy of index.html (index.prod.html) include any custom links you need in that index for that environment and inside angular.json add the following (the fileReplacement part):

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            },
            {
              "replace": "src/index.html",
              "with": "src/index.prod.html"
            }
          ]
        },
```

Please note this options is fixed and working on Angular 6.1 before that you couldn't use the `fileReplacements` for index files.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Mark Uretsky answer from **angular 8** version you shouldn't use fileReplacements.

Please use this:

```
      "index": {
        "input": "src/index.prod.html",
        "output": "index.html" // specify the path you want index.html to be generated.
      }
```